# Heapsort not working in Python for list of strings using heapq module

Tags: python, heapsort

I was reading the python 2.7 documentation when I came across the `heapq` module. I was interested in the heapify() and the heappop() methods. So, I decided to write a simple heapsort program for integers:

```
from heapq import heapify, heappop

user_input = raw_input("Enter numbers to be sorted: ")
data = map (int, user_input.split(","))
new_data = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    heapify(data)
    new_data.append(heappop(data))

print new_data
```

This worked like a charm.

To make it more interesting, I thought I would take away the integer conversion and leave it as a string. Logically, it should make no difference and the code should work as it did for integers:

```
from heapq import heapify, heappop
user_input = raw_input("Enter numbers to be sorted: ")
data = user_input.split(",")
new_data = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    heapify(data)
    print data
    new_data.append(heappop(data))

print new_data
```

Note: I added a print statement in the for loop to see the heapified list.
Here's the output when I ran the script:

```
`$ python heapsort.py 
Enter numbers to be sorted: 4, 3, 1, 9, 6, 2
[' 1', ' 3', ' 2', ' 9', ' 6', '4']
[' 2', ' 3', '4', ' 9', ' 6']
[' 3', ' 6', '4', ' 9']
[' 6', ' 9', '4']
[' 9', '4']
['4']
[' 1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 6', ' 9', '4']`
```

The reasoning I applied was that since the strings are being compared, the tree should be the same if they were numbers. As is evident, the heapify didn't work correctly after the third iteration. Could someone help me figure out if I am missing something here? I'm running Python 2.4.5 on RedHat 3.4.6-9.

Thanks,
VSN

Comment: Strings representing numbers aren't compared numerically. Also, you have spaces in your strings, and you don't need to keep heapifying after every pop.

Comment: I see how the spaces turned out to be the problem. But I do need to heapify after every pop. Otherwise, I don't see how the output would be sorted. Isn't that the basis of heapsort? Heapify -> Pop -> Heapify -> Pop... ?

Comment: Nope. `heappop` removes the top element and maintains the heap invariant. It's the whole reason it's *heap* pop instead of just regular pop. If you try it with regular pop, you'll find that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `strip` the spaces. They are the reason for this strange sorting. Sorting of strings is done character by character with ASCII codes.

So try:

```
from heapq import heapify, heappop
user_input = raw_input("Enter numbers to be sorted: ")
data = user_input.split(",")
data = map(str.strip, data)
new_data = []

heapify(data)
for i in range(len(data)):
    print(data)
    new_data.append(heappop(data))

print(new_data)
```

### Sorting

This question is rather about sorting than about `heapq`. And sorting itself in this context is essentially only about how `<` and `<=` works.

Sorting numbers works intuitively, but strings are different. Usually strings are sorted character by character by the bitpattern they use. This is the reason for the following behaviour

```
>>> sorted("abcABC")
['A', 'B', 'C', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

The ASCII code for `A` is 65 and for `a` it's 97 (see [ASCII Table](http://www.torsten-horn.de/techdocs/ascii.htm)).

The sorting is done character by character. If a string `a` is a prefix of another string `b`, it's always `a < b`.

```
>>> sorted(["123", "1", "2", "3", "12", "15", "20"])
['1', '12', '123', '15', '2', '20', '3']
```

What you want is called "natural sorting". See [`natsort`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort) for that.

Comment: `strip`ping the spaces away doesn't cut it. It just means you run into weirdness like 12<4.

Comment: @user2357112 Since 4 was first in the input, it was the only one without a space... moose is correct.  Try typing in the OP's program the input without any spaces at all and you'll see it works as expected.

Comment: @woot: It works like expected until you enter a 2-digit number, at which point everything promptly goes to hell again.

Comment: Depends on how you look at it, I guess. You sort on a string and that's the expected result. The OP just didn't think about the spaces in the front.

Comment: @moose You should move that heapify outside the loop, though, as user2357112 mentioned in the Question comments.

Comment: @user2357112: I did try his solution with 2 digit numbers and it worked.

Comment: @VSN: You didn't mix numbers of different lengths. Try it with `12, 4, 345`.

Comment: With that input, it doesn't matter whether the space exists or not. The method is incorrect as it is... Thanks!

Comment: @user2357112: I've added an explanation with the sorting behavior of Python. I hope this helps.